# What is WndProc message 24

Tags: vb.net, nullpointerexception, wndproc

I am currently trying to make an existing VB.NET Project run. A null pointer exception is thrown in the WndProc message but the stack trace does not really give me anything. I can place a break point in the startup form's designer code but when I step through it triggers a NULL pointer exception via WndProc function. The upper methods seems to be Windows methods. The only clue I have is the Message parameter with Msg = 24 and WParam = 1. I think the HWnd = 5178884 does not help.

I am pasting the stack trace in case someone has any ideas.
**Note**: I masked the MyNamespace and MyBaseForm and MyFormA because the source code is proprietary. This runs in Visual Studio 2008 on .NET Framework 3.5

```
MyNamespace.Forms.MyBaseForm.WndProc(Message& m)\r\n   
System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)\r\n   
System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)\r\n   
System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)\r\n   
System.Windows.Forms.SafeNativeMethods.ShowWindow(HandleRef hWnd, Int32 nCmdShow)\r\n   
System.Windows.Forms.Control.SetVisibleCore(Boolean value)\r\n   
System.Windows.Forms.Form.SetVisibleCore(Boolean value)\r\n   
System.Windows.Forms.Control.set_Visible(Boolean value)\r\n   
System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoopInner(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)\r\n   
System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoop(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)\r\n   
System.Windows.Forms.Application.Run(ApplicationContext context)\r\n   
Microsoft.VisualBasic.ApplicationServices.WindowsFormsApplicationBase.OnRun()\r\n   
Microsoft.VisualBasic.ApplicationServices.WindowsFormsApplicationBase.DoApplicationModel()\r\n   
Microsoft.VisualBasic.ApplicationServices.WindowsFormsApplicationBase.Run(String[] commandLine)\r\n   
MyFormA.My.MyApplication.Main(String[] Args) 
17d14f5c-a337-4978-8281-53493378c1071.vb:Line 81\r\n   
System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(Assembly assembly, String[] args)\r\n   
System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFile, Evidence assemblySecurity, String[] args)\r\n   
Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()\r\n   
System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)\r\n   
System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)\r\n   
System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`WM_SHOWWINDOW = 24`

...not that it really helps.
It looks like the last bit of your code to be executed is **line 81**, I'd study that.

Comment: Thanks. I am guessing that the line 81 call is from the system api since it called MyFormA.My.MyApplication.Main. probably part of visual studio. that name is a guid. it may not be the cause.

Comment: Just to add here is the reference to WM_SHOWWINDOW. http://winapi.freetechsecrets.com/win32/WIN32WMSHOWWINDOW.htm

Answer (score 0):

I just want to give another answer on how to know where the error came from even if the stack trace did not tell you anything (The actual problem why I asked what is WndProc 24). Just in case other people had the same problem too.

I used the Unhandled Exception via Debug > Exceptions menu on Visual Studio. See this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/176839/how-can-i-break-on-an-unhandled-exception-in-asp-net) for detail.

Maintaining the point to C.Barlow as he answered the initial question.